# Validate function calls a other function too many times

Tags: python, tkinter

Hi i am writing simple typing sped in test in python using tkinter for gui, but i ran into a problem. I want the text in label to change every time the user writes the tenth sentence in entry widget, but when i wrote tenth sentence text in label is changing for example when this word has 5 letters text is changing 5 times. I know why it's hapenning but i don't know how to fix it. thanks.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import END
import tkinter.font as font
import random, sys

start = False

# configure tkinter windows
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x600")
# set window as not resizable
root.resizable(height=False, width=False)
root.title("typing speed test")

# create fonts
myFont = font.Font(size=30)
txtFont = font.Font(size=40)
#this font is needed to entry widget
midFont = font.Font(size=20)


def get_words():
    """
    this function open's file and returns
    list with content from it
    """
    filename = "words.txt"
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            contents = f.read()
            #return 10 random words from list
            num = random.randrange(0, 990)
            contents = contents.split()
            return contents[num:num+10]
    except FileNotFoundError:
        sys.exit("file not founded")


def countdown(count):
    """
    this function create timer in tkinter
    window
    """
    global start
    start = True
    # change text and font in label
    countdown_label['font'] = myFont
    countdown_label['text'] = count

    if count > 0:
        # call countdown again after 1000ms (1s)
        root.after(1000, countdown, count-1)

    if count <= 10:
        # change color of texts
        countdown_label["fg"] = "#f00"

    if count == 0:
        # when count equal 0 disable entry widget
        e.config(state='disabled')

#create label
textlabel = tk.Label(root, width=60, height=10, font=midFont, text = "siema")
#add text to label
textlabel.config(text=get_words())

def onValidate(P):
    """
    Tkinter validate function
    """
    global words
    words = P.split()
    if P.isalpha() and start == False:
        # start counting when user starts
        countdown(100)
    if len(words) % 10 == 0 :
        textlabel.config(text=get_words())
    return True

def comapreLists():
    """
    This function compare two
    lists and return set with
    word(s) if it exist in l0
    lists
    """
    #this list stores words from entry widget
    l0 = words
    #this list stores words from file
    l2 = get_words()
    # compare lists
    dn = set(l0).intersection(l2)
    # return values
    return dn

#it's button created only for debug
b = tk.Button(root, text='COMP', command=comapreLists)
#register validate func
vcmd = (root.register(onValidate), '%P')
#create label for timer
countdown_label = tk.Label(root)
#create entry window
e = tk.Entry(validate="key", validatecommand=vcmd,
             width=30, font=myFont, state='normal')
#pack elements 
countdown_label.pack()
textlabel.pack()
b.pack()

e.place(anchor='center', x=399, y=500)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use another global variable to store the current number of words entered, then update `textLabel` only if current number of words not equal to saved one.

```py
last_cnt = 0

def onValidate(P):
    """
    Tkinter validate function
    """
    global words, last_cnt

    if P.isalpha() and start == False:
        # start counting when user starts
        countdown(100)

    words = P.split()
    cnt = len(words)
    if cnt and (cnt % 10 == 0) and (cnt != last_cnt):
        textlabel.config(text=get_words())
    last_cnt = cnt

    return True
```